# Which method is called when setting UIButton's title in interface builder?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

does anyone know, which method is called when I set the default title of a UIButton in interface builder?

[image]

I have subclassed UIButton and want to provide setting its title easily via interface builder. I assume that it works similar to the User Defined Runtime Attributes which call the setValue: forKeyPath: method.

Edit: So I'm looking for that method which works like "the interface builder tells the button to have that certain title" when instantiating the view.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're confused; you seem to imply that your subclass will actually be *running* while it's being edited in IB?

Comment: It may be that I get you wrong but... when I set a title in interface builder and then run my app there sure has to be a method call which is like "interface builder tells the button to have this certain title". Or is this working otherwise?

Comment: OK, you're not confused.  Your question could be better stated (like what you just wrote in that comment).

Answer (score 1):

Interface Builder doesn't call setTitle: method, instead you can override initWithCoder: and awakeFromNib in your UIButton's subclass

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder){

        NSLog([self titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]);

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: But to retrieve the title that I set in the interface builder I have to do something like `NSString * myTitle = [aCoder decodeObjectForKey:@"xyz"]`. Do you know what to set as key ("xyz")?

Answer (score 0):

The method you're looking for is [`setTitle:forState:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle%3aforState%3a).

Comment: Yeah I checked for that. My class receives a call when i use the User Defined Runtime Attributes but when I check for setTitle:forState: nothing is called in my subclass.... :-/ This led me to the opinion that there might be another method which gets called when setting the default title.

Comment: It might be a private method.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, setValue:forKeyPath: isn't called either on my subclass. So this might count for setTitle:forState:, too. I need to check that again... ;)

Comment: Did you try `setValue:forKey:`?

Comment: But the problem with that is, that it's simply called when the title changes, which is not the same as `setTitle:forState:`.

Comment: hm, ok, weird... I get a string value but not the one I inserted in the interface builder. I have to research that.